# Query all non-dba users from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new to SQL and was wondering if someone could please help me out with a query to list all non-DBA users from either the current database and potentially also the entire server (all databases).

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. **We are here to help in your code**, if you haven't tried anything then we cant help much. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.

Comment: Just searching "sql server get database users" returns a lot of interesting results, including this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/listing-the-existing-sql-server-logins-and-users

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the DBAs are member of the Sysadmin role, you can do the following to check members who aren't member of the Sysadmin role.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            s.name AS principal_name
FROM    sys.server_principals s
INNER JOIN sys.server_permissions p ON s.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id
WHERE   s.type IN ( 's', 'u' )
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM   sys.server_role_members m
                INNER JOIN sys.server_principals sp 
                ON m.role_principal_id = sp.principal_id
                WHERE  s.principal_id = m.member_principal_id
                AND sp.name = 'sysadmin' );
```